# Counting rows with a condition

Tags: mysql

i work with a table "ships" like this:

```
shipid
container1
container2
```

**shipid** and **container1** are always filled, **container2** is optional.

This is my query for now:

```
SELECT COUNT(container1) FROM table
```

How can i achieve that this query counts the amount of the container2's too?!

It must be a joined query made of those both queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(container1) FROM table
SELECT COUNT(container2) FROM table WHERE container2!=''
```

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: Do you want to sum container1 and container2 counts or have the counts separately? The question is not clear

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(container1) FROM table
UNION
SELECT COUNT(container2) FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SUM`

```
SELECT 
     SUM(container1) AS c1
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN container2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c2
FROM ships
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answers, you can do this to get the count in 1 result.

```
 SELECT SUM(count) FROM
  (
   SELECT COUNT(container1) as count FROM table
   UNION ALL
   SELECT COUNT(container2) as count FROM table
  ) as a
```

or you can do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
  (
   SELECT container1  FROM table
   UNION ALL
   SELECT container2  FROM table
  ) as a
```